# How Do I Determine Who Profits From A Given Shooting Sports Event?

Tags: united-states, target-shooting

I am getting back into shooting sports and now that the pandemic is definitively coming to a middle, I'm starting to think about the future and when I might go try and find a match. Given what's been going on with the NRA lately, I'm not interested in any fees I pay going to their benefit.

When I'm considering signing up for an event, how can I determine where the proceeds are going? Is it even possible (my friends insist it's not) to shoot in competitions without *de facto* sponsoring the NRA?

Comment: I think the _de facto_ part of the question is mildly opinion based. The question might be better suited for the site without that final line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest straight up asking the competition organisers.

If they're reluctant to tell you then there's something to hide, not saying it's the mob but it could be the mob. If it's the NRA or a local shooting club they'll probably declare it directly.

It's not really something anyone should have any reason to hide.